# how to only copy executable files( or files without extension) in linux?

Tags: linux

Suppose there is a directory named mydir containing ...

```
aaa.cpp
aaa.h
bbb.cpp
bbb.h
Makefile
a 
b
```

... where a,b are executable files. What I want to is to only copy a and b to another location.

Is it possible ? (other than by manually issuing `copy a,b another_dir` )

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can run:

```
find mydir -perm /a+x -exec cp {} destdir \;
```

Comment: it works,but directory also in the results of find

Comment: Add "-type f" (match files only)

Comment: Great! it works

Comment: For some reason, this copied .c and .h files as well as executables on RHEL

Answer (score 6):

You should add a rule in your `Makefile` to `install` your executable targets.

Comment: it is a good idea, but it is a temporary work,so I didn't want to write a Makefile for it